# Growing a thicker beard

Tags: personal-care, shaving

I was wondering if there any tips, diets to make my beard thicker, It grows at a healthy rate(length wise) but it's not as thick as I would want to.

Comment: It's simply not possible to encourage extra hair growth by home means.